# button (assign APPS SCRIPT to object/image) in GOOGLE SHEETS to initiate recalculation for volatile functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i created a "button" to trigger updating volatile formulas in Google Sheets by assigning a script (set & clear a cell) to an image/object; i am curious if there is a simpler way/script to create such a button (i.e., one that doesn't require setting/clearing a cell).

update function below;

link to sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z98qH07-r2Q_Q9IHzKVinLbLPaVbghskU61G0egiWz0/edit#gid=2044689989

```js
// update
function update() {
  var none = SS.getRange('C1')
  none.setValue('none');
  none.clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

If you look at `File -> Spreadsheet Settings` menu and go to `Calculation` tab you will see that every option on Recalculation **requires a change in the spreadsheet**.

It also applies to Apps Script as well. It works on the same principle that Apps Script cannot evaluate Sheet formulas.

But you don't need to set a dummy value to a cell beforehand to force recalculation. Clearing it's content is enough.

```
function update() {
  var none = SS.getRange('C1')
  none.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response—both the confirmation of the change-required and the shorter function (one less line of code is one less line).